# Find all semidirect products $\mathbb{Z}_{8} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_{4}$ up to isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

I am trying to solve this:

> Find all semidirect products $\mathbb{Z}_{8} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_{4}$ up to isomorphism

First I tried to find all homomorphisms $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}_{4} \to{\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{8})$. As $\varphi$ is only decided by the value $\varphi(\overline{1})(\overline{1})$, I find there are 4 different homomorphisms $\varphi$.They are $\varphi_{1}(\overline{1})(\overline{1})=\overline{1}$, $\varphi_{2}(\overline{1})(\overline{1})=\overline{3}$, $\varphi_{3}(\overline{1})(\overline{1})=\overline{5}$ and $\varphi_{4}(\overline{1})(\overline{1})=\overline{7}$.
$\varphi_{1}$ is the identity mapping so $\mathbb{Z}_{8} \rtimes_{\varphi_{1}} \mathbb{Z}_{4}$ is not isomorphic to the other three. But I don't know what to do next. I have no idea about whether $\mathbb{Z}_{8} \rtimes_{\varphi_{2}} \mathbb{Z}_{4}$, $\mathbb{Z}_{8} \rtimes_{\varphi_{3}} \mathbb{Z}_{4}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{8} \rtimes_{\varphi_{4}} \mathbb{Z}_{4}$ are isomorphic. I tried to prove they are isomorphic but failed. So maybe they are not isomorphic, but I also do not know how to prove two groups are not isomorphic. Is there a better way to solve this? Thank you for help.

Comment: Hint: If $\langle x\rangle$ is the subgroup of order $8$ then $x$ and one of $x^3,x^5,x^{-1}$ is conjugate to $x$. In the first case, we see that $x^3$ is conjugate to $x=(x^3)^3$. If $x^5$ is conjugate to $(x^5)^3=x^{-1}$ then we see that all elements of order $8$ are conjugate to their third powers only.

Comment: No pair of those groups is isomorphic. The easiest way to prove two groups are not isomorphic is to identify a group-theoretical property that is different. The group defined with $\phi_3$ has a larger centre than the other two (it has $x^4$ in its centre), so that is not too hard to show.  The other two groups are more difficult. One way of doing it is to show that the $\phi_4$-group has elements of order $8$ that are conjugate to their inverse, whereas the $\phi_2$-group does not, but that is not completely starightforward.